# "to be" deletion

Tags: infinitives

I knew that **consider** allows **to be** deletion.

> Everybody considers him to be the best person for the job.

This sentence can be written in the following way:

> Everybody considers him the best person for the job.

It seems to me that, the second sentence is also correct. I would like to have the list of verbs which don't allow **to be** deletion, and the list of verbs that allow **to be** deletion.

Comment: *to be* is an atribution, implicitly exposed when not using it.

Comment: loose synonyms of "consider".... deem, think, hold, judge, believe, suppose,  imagine, reckon

Comment: @TRomano the last four of that list don't seem to allow the omission of "to be".

Comment: @modulusshift They will all accommodate a bare PC, with no copula. The construction is relatively rare these days, but so is that with *to be*; the trend is to complement these with a content clause. *I suppose him honest*, *I suppose him to be honest*, *I suppose that he is honest*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the notion of *to be **deletion*** very dubious. There are many verbs which take nominal or adjectival predicative complements (**PC**s), only some of which will also accommodate an infinitival complement, so it seems to me more accurate to speak of *to be **insertion***.  Huddleston & Pullum (**H&P** below), *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, appear to agree: their *Classification of verbs taking predicative complements* (263-266) distinguishes with the sign <sub><sup>INF</sup></sub> those verbs which may take infinitival complements.

Here are H&P's lists of 'complex' verbs—verbs which take PCs; those which also take Objects are transitive, those which do not take objects are intransitive.

- *Depictive* PCs describe the Subject or Object (*He looks honest, I consider him honest*); *resultative* PCs tell what the Subject or Object became as a result of the action of the verb (*He grew angry, This makes me angry*).
- The sign <sub><sup>ADJ</sup></sub> marks verbs which ordinarily take only *adjectival* PCs (*He looks kingly*, but not **He looks king*), and the sign <sub><sup>NP</sup></sub> marks verbs which ordinarily take only *nominal* PCs (*They elected him king*, but not **They elected him kingly*).

> Class 1 verbs: complex-intransitives with depictive PCs
>   [image: CIdepic]
>
> Class 2 verbs: complex-intransitives with resultative PCs
>   [image: CIres]
>
> Class 3 verbs: complex-transitives with depictive PCs'. 
>   [image: CTdepic]

H&P also remark that 'A few verbs not included above, such as *acknowledge, confess, suppose*, appear in the complex-transitive, but normally only with a reflexive object'. I cannot agree with this judgment; I've seen all three with non-reflexive objects.

> Class 4 verbs: complex-transitives with obligatory resultative PCs
>   [image: CTobres]

H&P also give representative list of 'Class 5 verbs: complex-transitives with optional resultatives', commenting that 'There are many verbs of this type, usually taking a small range of AdjPs'.

Note that many of these may also take PCs with *as* (*They elected him as Chairman*) or content clauses with the verb's object as subject (*They considered him honest*, *They considered that he was honest*).

These lists should not be regarded as comprehensive, but they probably include most verbs in ordinary use.

Comment: Thanks for your nice and useful answer. I cannot understand  "Here are H&P's lists. The sign ADJ marks verbs which ordinarily take only adjectival PCs, and the sign NP marks verbs which ordinarily take only nominal PCs". Would you like to give some examples to explain it. I would be very happy, if you do this for me.

Comment: There needs to be a 'should be on ELU' button to press.